# How can I collect cell models associated with a given channel model using NeuroML Database API?

Tags: neuroml-database

I want to associate a subset of channel models in the NeuroML Database with the cell models they're embedded in. I'm wondering if there is a quick and easy way to get all the associated cells for a given channel model.

Here's the "first" channel model on the web portal (https://neuroml-db.org/model_info?model_id=NMLCH000001). It says that it belongs to a cell model toward the bottom.

I've collected all channel model details ("Type":"CH") using https://neuroml-db.org/api/models?id=NMLCHxxxxxx so I have the JSON for each channel model I want to look at. I can't find an "Associated Cell" field.

Is there a place with a list for all the NMLCLxxxxxx for associated cells? I may be missing it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get all cell models to which a channel model is associated with using the `parents` key of the model API.**

### Example

For example, [this channel](https://neuroml-db.org/model_info?model_id=NMLCH000134) shows it is included in the following cell models:

[image]

To get the list of those cells from the API:

In the channel model detail API url:
https://neuroml-db.org/api/model?id=NMLCH000134

Find the top-level `parents` key in resulting JSON, which lists all of the above cell models and some of their detail:

[image]